# Responsive web design column appearing below

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, css-grid

So I have been trying to make a responsive web page and this was supposed to be the outcome.
[image]

When I tried to add the second column after the profile, it appears below it instead like this for some reason.
[image]

No matter what I applied from what I learned, the box appears below. I can only guess that the borders here affect the columns, not making it able to fit even when I resized my browser to make such a thing happen when it clearly didn't look like it.

This is what I did in the CSS file:

```css
/* rows and column */
.row::after{
 content: ””;
 clear: both;
 display: table;
}
[class*=”column-”]{
 float: left;
 padding: 2px;
 width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
 .column-1 {width: 8.33%;}
 .column-2 {width: 16.66%;}
 .column-3 {width: 25%;}
 .column-4 {width: 33.33%;}
 .column-5 {width: 41.66%;}
 .column-6 {width: 50%;}
 .column-7 {width: 58.33%;}
 .column-8 {width: 66.66%;}
 .column-9 {width: 75%;}
 .column-10 {width: 83.33%;}
 .column-11 {width: 91.66%;}
 .column-12 {width: 100%;}
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* css class selector */
.menu{
  max-width:100%;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.menu li {
   padding: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   background-color:#1CA2BB;
   color: white;
}
.menu li:hover {
   background-color: #58DADA;
}
.menu .subject{
  background-color:#005792;
  font-size:20px;
}
.border-subjects{
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border:5px solid #F7B633;
}
.border-profile{
  padding:5px;
  border:5px solid #F7B633;
}
.header-content{
  background-color:#005E7C;
  color: white;
  font-size:25px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  position:sticky;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-align:right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* css element selector */
img{
  display:block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: auto;
  width: 130px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/* css id selector*/
#img-android{
max-width: 100%;
width:89px;
height: auto;
}
```

```
As for the HTML...

<!-- language: html -->

    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Responsive Web Page</title>
        <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="row header-content">
          <div class="column-12">
            Juan Dela Cruz
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of div: header -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column-3 border-profile">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column-12">
                <img src="https://simg.nicepng.com/png/small/128-1280406_view-user-icon-png-user-circle-icon-png.png"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="column-12">
                <p>Name: Juan Dela Cruz</p>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 menu">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      Home
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      Subjects
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      Assignment
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      Quiz
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      About
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of row: menu -->
          </div>
          <!-- end of row:profile -->
          <div class="column-9 border-subjects">
            <img src="https://simg.nicepng.com/png/small/128-1280406_view-user-icon-png-user-circle-icon-png.png"/>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The border-subjects was supposed to fit and be in the same size as the profile. How am I supposed to adjust the subjects to appear in the same row as the profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Basically what you looking for is a CSS style to do the layout in the correct way .

The style could be done as a grid or a flexbox .
I prefer a flex box as its responsive with different screen sizes as well as can scale with different size content / You also can hide overflow and scroll if you wish .

A grid element is not nearly as responsive and in most cases your content is fixed to the grids inline space .where as a flexbox can scale with content.
Additionally Flexbox also allows you to decide how your content should behave when there’s too much space or not enough space on the screen whereas a grid is more "rigid" in terms of the CSS rules

Here I nest the individual element in a flex box

```css
html {
  background: #f6faff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -0.5rem;
}
.item {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background: #f3edd6;
  border: 3px solid #b59214;
  color: #b59214;
  padding: 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">long content long content long content long content long content</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

For more details of a comparison on a  flexbox or a grid refer to a comparison article
[Flexbox Vs Grid](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/flexbox-vs-css-grid-which-should-you-use--cms-30184)

and for full details on a flexbox this article is comprehensive
[Complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Oh, we haven't reached the point of Flexbox yet, so we're basically grounded to using the GridView specifically. Although I appreciate the fact you brought up Flexbox because it would prepare me ahead of the subject matter next week.

Comment: Ok in that case you want to go through each CSS element that says width 100% and change those 
[class*=”column-”]{
 float: left;
 padding: 2px;
 width: 100%;
}